# UnsupportedOperationException when trying to remove from the list returned by Array.asList

Tags: java, exception, list

I am using a `List` to hold some data obtained by calling `Array.asList()` method. Then I am trying to remove an element using `myList.Remove(int i)` method. But while I try to do that I am getting an `UnsupportedOperationException`. What would be the reason for this? How should I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`Array.asList()` *wraps* an array in the list interface. The list is still backed by the array. Arrays are a fixed size - they don't support adding or removing elements, so the wrapper can't either.

The docs don't make this as clear as they might, but they *do* say:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

The "fixed-size" bit should be a hint that you can't add or remove elements :)

Although there are other ways around this (other ways to create a new `ArrayList` from an array) without extra libraries, I'd personally recommend getting hold of the [Google Collections Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) (or [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), when it's released). You can then use:

```
List<Integer> list = Lists.newArrayList(array);
```

The reason I'm suggesting this is that the GCL is a generally good thing, and well worth using.

As noted in comments, this takes a *copy* of the array; the list is not backed by the original array, and changes in either collection will not be seen in the other.

Comment: Agreed.  However, I think it's worth noting that the original method does return a list that is backed by the original array, and changes "write-through" to the original array.  Using this will not return a List that is backed by the original array, and any changes in this returned List will NOT affect the original array.

Comment: Ideologically and even semantically, this is very weird and to my understanding - wrong implementation of `.asList()` method. It returns the implementation of `List`, which, by default, is an implementation of `Dynamic Array`. So, it's very odd, that Dynamic Array implementation is a fixed-size array.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri: What do you mean by "which, by default, is an implementation of Dynamic Array"? `List<E>` is explicitly documented in various places to have operations that may not be supported by all implementations. Likewise, there are static methods (`List.of` and `List.copyOf`) which return unmodifiable lists. `asList()` is behaving exactly as documented, so how can it be a "wrong implementation"?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I mean, that why would anyone in the world use `List` implementation reference types? the primary reason is to have an implementation of `Dynamic Array` ADT, exposing methods for adding and removing elements dynamically. All the popular implementations of it (as far as I know) implement exactly - the Dynamic Array idea. If some instance of List and some other instance of List differ in the behaviour, just because of the way how they were created, this brings quite unsteady and inconsistent picture to me.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri: "I mean, that why would anyone in the world use List implementation reference types". I'm not sure what you mean by "List implementation reference types" but there's plenty of reason to use `List<E>` for read-only indexed access and availability of the size. Many, many uses of `List<E>` don't require it to be mutable at all. It would be nice if there were an interface expressing that (as there is in .NET for example) but `List<E>` is a very old interface.

Comment: @JonSkeet, exactly - there must be a discrete/separate interface for this. I think from the general perspective. Look, we have a `List` interface, right? and we know from the definition of Interface, that in OOP, it defines the contract, it declares the bahaviour of its implementer classes. Now, I'd like to overview this from the polymorphic perspective, that different implementations must have same API of behaviour. And boom.. one implementer will have `add`, another - will not. That's really awkward.
In `List implementation reference types` I mean classes, which implement List.

Comment: "there must be a discrete/separate interface for this" - but there isn't. Maybe that was a design mistake, but that's the way it's been for 20 years, and `Array.asList()` is providing a valid implementation of it as designed and specified. Stack Overflow really isn't the place to say "I think the Java collection interfaces should be designed differently."

Answer (score 28):

It's not `java.util.ArrayList`. `Arrays.asList()` returns its own `List` implementation (with changes "written through" to the array.).

It's a **fixed-size** list so it does not support removal.

You can create a real `ArrayList` from it:

```
new java.util.ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(someArray));
```

It's very confusing how `asList()` works, I must admit.

Answer (score 8):

Please read the API docs for [Arrays.asList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list
> "write through" to the array.)

Note that Collections.remove(int) is marked in the Javadocs as an "optional operation", meaning not all Collections will support it. "fixed-size list" means you cannot change the list's size, which remove() would do. So it's not supported.

If you want to change the list generated by Arrays.asList(), just copy it, e.g. `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(...))`.

Answer (score 6):

The implementation you receive from asList doesn't implement a full List interface. I would transform the list to ArrayList and then do modifications on it.

See [remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29).

Comment: You mean iterating over this list and put all the objects to an ArrayList at the beginning??

Comment: no, the ArrayList constructor takes a Collection as an argument, so you can just call new ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Because you get read-only list.
try

```
List newList = new ArrayList(myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

> ArrayList instead of List

List has fixed size element, List can neither addition item nor remove item