# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException on addAll method on an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, list, exception, arraylist

I am trying to add the whole list to another list

```
       for(String lob: lobs) {
            if(subLobs.contains(lob)) {
                bankCodes.addAll(additionalBankCodes);
                break;
            }
        }
```

The above piece of code throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. Not sure what is the reason.

Note: all the variable names used are ArrayLists which is not empty.

Comment: what are all the variables? Please share minimal testable code.

Comment: Provide a runnable example that demonstrates your problem. BankCodes could be created from Arrays.toList or have been wrapped in an unmodifiable wrapper

Comment: You can probably solve it with something like `bankCodes = new ArrayList<BankCodes>(bankCodes);` before this loop, but more code would be necessary to give a definite answer here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624144/unsupportedoperationexception-for-tarray-aslist-removeint

Answer (score 1):

It Seems you are creating your List as :-

1. Arrays.asList() : This creates an fixed Length array list where you cannot do add or remove.
2. Collections.unmodifiableList(...);

Regards,
Vikram

Answer (score 0):

As per the exception you might using some unmodifiable List and trying to add item in it.

[UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that the requested operation is not supported.

sample code:

```
List<String> bankCodes = Collections.unmodifiableList(...);
```

since `bankCodes` list can't be modifiable hence result in above exception.

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.singletonList` returns an immutable list like `Arrays.asList`. If you are using singletonList, this may also be the cause of the `UnsupportedOperationException`.