# How to write a comparator to compare all the elements of a list to a input and move to top

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

**I have a List**

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("1234", "1214", "1334");
```

**My input is**:

```
String mInput = "1214"
```

---

How to write a comparator to compare all the elements of `myList` to `mInput` and if it is equal, move it to the top of the list

Comment: A comparator should just compare, not move stuff around. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: Hmm 20k rep and rather rookie question - what is happening here? Is it A TRAP?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca .... i can sort using `comparator`, is it possible to achieve as it in question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting Strings that contains number in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973503/sorting-strings-that-contains-number-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own `Comparator`:

```
class BringToFrontComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<T> {
    T front;

    public BringToFrontComparator(T front) {
        this.front = front;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        return o1.equals(front) && !o2.equals(front)
                // Front one is always less than anything other than itself.
                ? -1
                // Normal comparison elsewhere.
                : o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}

public void test(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("1234", "1214", "1334");
    String mInput = "1334";
    Collections.sort(myList, new BringToFrontComparator<>(mInput));
    System.out.println(myList);
}
```

prints

> [1334, 1214, 1234]

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a comparator you can use :

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1234", "1214", "1334"));
String mInput = "1214";
if (myList.contains(mInput)) {
    myList.remove(mInput);// remove mInput 
    myList.add(0, mInput);// add it to to index 0 (top of list)
}
System.out.println(myList);// Input [1214, 1234, 1334]
```

---

Note you have to use `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1234", "1214", "1334"))` to understand why, you can read this [UnsupportedOperationException when trying to remove from the list returned by Array.asList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624144/unsupportedoperationexception-when-trying-to-remove-from-the-list-returned-by-ar)

Comment: Thank you , this also helps ... [+1]

Answer (score 1):

If you really need comparator here, you can do something like this (assuming that `mInput` is not `null`):
 `myList.sort((String o1, String o2) -> mInput.equals(o1) && !mInput.equals(o2) ? -1 : o1.compareTo(o2));`

Comment: This violates the Comparator contract. if o1 and o2 both equal myInput you have both o1 < o2 and o2 < o1.

Comment: Comparator will return -1 in that case, so what's the problem?

Comment: As I just said, you'll have both o1 < o2 and o2 < o1, depending if you use o1.compareTo(o2) or o2.compareTo(o1). This is invalid.

Comment: I hope I fixed that