# using lombok builder with an abstract class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have this abstract class:

```
public abstract class Hotel {

     protected List<String> defaultValues() {
        return List.of("Geeks", "For", "Geeks");
    }
}
```

and this lombok class that extends from the abstract class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Hostel extends Hotel {         
    private List<String> values = defaultValues();    

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static class HosteBuilder {

        public Hostel build() {    
            this.values.add("ww");    
            ...
        }
    }    
}
```

but I get a nullpointer in the line `values.add("ww");`

Comment: This shouldn't even compile.

Comment: `defaultValues()` returns an **immutable** list. Why do you think you can add to it? Immutable means something cannot be changed. Addition is a change.

Comment: `HosteBuilder` cannot use the field `values` of `Hostel`, since its a static inner class. It holds no reference to the enclosing class.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but lombok is _not_ a Java beginner tool. You should be really familiar with all Java programming language constructs before you start using lombok, especially when you are using the more complex lombok features like `@Builder`. Furthermore, when you have to suppress warnings, that's in most cases a sign that something is wrong. Here, you have a typo in your builder class name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Builder class needs to create a new instance first. But also, the list you are using is Immutable. Both these issues have been noted by user Michael. In any case, lombok is *not to blame* for any of this, as it only adds methods, none of which you are using in your example.

First, change the list to a mutable list type:

```java
return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Geeks", "For", "Geeks"});
```

And the extending type to:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Hostel extends Hotel {         
    private List<String> values = defaultValues();    

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static class HosteBuilder {

        public Hostel build() {
            Hostel hostel = new Hostel();
            hostel.values.add("ww");    
            // ...
            return hostel;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList` actually is not a good choice. It is a view of the given array. It is mutable because elements can be reordered or replaced, but you cannot add elements because the backing array is a fixed size.

Comment: Actually `Arrays.asList` returns an `ArrayList` (in Java 8), which is a standard (low memory) list type, which elements can easiely be added to. The array backing the list is copied into a larger array, on demand.

Comment: If you are going to correct me, please double check that you are actually correct. It returns a class **called** `ArrayList`, but it is not the one most people are familiar with. It is a private static class within `Arrays`, and functions how I already described. Here is a [runnable example](https://ideone.com/048Ums), and [an answer by Jon Skeet explaining the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1624163/1898563)